# Exporting results from SQL Server 2014 into pipe delimited text format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen a few things around the web on how to do this yet none seem to work. I am basically just running a query and need to somehow get the results into pipe delimited text format, its all the client will accept. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Export Wizard to do this:

- Right click on your database
- Navigate to tasks
- Pick Export Data

[image: Pick Export Data Task]

- Choose SQL Server as a data source

[image: Source]

- Choose flat file as a target

[image: Target]

- Pick either table or query from
- Select your column delimiter and export.

[image: Delimiter]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Export Wizard of Sql Server 2014 , add in your query and specify the file format.
See the steps in the following links:

- SQL Server Central : http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/waterox-sql/2014/08/19/export-a-ssms-query-result-set-to-csv/
- MSDN :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052(v=sql.120).aspx